# Object Serialization -Binaryformatter , how to write at the and / insert data with in already existing file?

Tags: c#, winforms, io, binary, .net

i want to write my file which contains list of file names , i am storing this local disk,

whenever i write the file , all existing data are erasing and new data is over writing , i am failing to keep the existing data and start writing after the line of existing data

my  Binary format writer codes goes like this

```
private object ReadFileToUI(string filename)
    {
        Stream readStr = File.OpenRead(filename);
        BinaryFormatter rbf = new BinaryFormatter();
        object obj= rbf.Deserialize(readStr);
        readStr.Close();
        return obj;


    }
```

and my binary writer goes like thsi ,

```
   Stream str = File.OpenWrite(fileName);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(str, fl);
        str.Close();
```

suppose if i have already 10 objects inside the file , any new writing should be treated as the 11th and onward so on  and previous data should not be affected in the file ??

Comment: You might try a StreamWriter.  I believe that lets you specify that you will be appending data to a file rather than overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

Open your stream like this...

```
Stream str = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write);
```

Comment: "Stream was not readable. This is error i am getting if i replace your code .. any idea?